# Anonymous Type Name Collision

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

A linq query that returns an anonymous type throws the following error when executed.

```
The type '<>f__AnonymousType9<Name,Value>' exists in both    
'Customer.CustomerWeb.Presentation.dll' and 'Customer.CustomerContext.dll'
```

Using `JetBrains dotPeek` I was able to find that there is are 2 compiler generated classes that collide.

**Customer.CustomerContext.dll**

```
 internal sealed class <>f__AnonymousType9<<PayrollSiteID>j__TPar, <IsActive>j__TPar>
```

**Customer.CustomerWeb.Presentation.dll**

```
 internal sealed class <>f__AnonymousType9<<Name>j__TPar, <Value>j__TPar>
```

Both of the generated classes are in the root `namespace`. Is there any way I can direct `Anonymous Type classes` to a particular namespace on each assembly? The easy fix is to add a third variable to one of the anonymous queries, however this is more of a hack.

Comment: You haven't shown the queries, but another easy fix is surely to create a named, non-anonymous type.

Comment: Is this compile time error?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel This is a runtime error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that defeats the purpose of Anonymous Type

Comment: Anything unusual about how you're loading the assemblies?

Comment: @Baldrick 
Customer.CustomerWeb.Presentation is the main assembly (asp.net web site) 
Customer.CustomerContext is just a referenced project.

Comment: Could you show the LINQ query associated with it? And the exception details (stack trace in particular). Also, does one of the mentioned libraries give internals access to another library?

Comment: Can you show us what is the namespace of both the types? and code where you call it? and the line which throws this exception? btw what is the type of exception?

Comment: I can see ASP.Net being a problem here somehow.

Comment: @JeanHominal I just removed all the InternalsVisibleTo attributes. They were irrelevant and did not make a difference.

Comment: @JeanHominal I feel that the query is irelivent. i was able to just create the problem by replacing the linq with `var x = new {Name="",Value=""}`

Comment: @Chad When is the exception raised? What is the exception's type and stack trace?

Comment: It results in a StackOverFlow. In order to get `The type '<>f__AnonymousType9<Name,Value>' exists in both    
'Customer.CustomerWeb.Presentation.dll' and 'Customer.CustomerContext.dll'` I have to drop a breakpoint before the crash. Inspecting the variable is when I get that message.

Comment: Oh crap. A Stack overflow. The absolute worst in debuggability. In that case, the message that you get may not be relevant to the actual error - you have to identify the chain of calls that leads to the stack overflow. One of the methods to do that would be to instrument your app, e.g. by adding logging statements when entering methods, or by using a profiling tool. Also, does the crash happen on start, or when a particular action is triggered?

Comment: Since both classes are marked internal they names shouldn't collide - maybe one of your assemblies uses InternalsVisibleTo attribute to show its internals to another...

Comment: "Inspecting the variable is when I get that message" -> that sounds like a debugger problem, not a problem in your actual program. Are you using Visual Studio or something else? What version? I've never seen this happening in Visual Studio.

Comment: have you tried rebuild. i think it should solve issue. if you don't want to create class you can use Tuple<t,t> class

Comment: I'm with @KrisVandermotten on this one.  This sounds like a red herring /debugger problem.  The real issue is the SO and conflict in class names isn't going to cause that. For me 9 times out of 10 SO means I'm accessing a property where I meant to be accessing a field.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like the following, where you add your using statement inside the namespace to give it preference in name resolution:

```
using Customer.CustomerContext;
namespace yourNameSpace
{
    using Customer.CustomerWeb.Presentation; //Where f__AnonymousType9<Name,Value> exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments

> It results in a StackOverFlow. In order to get `The type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType9<Name,Value>' exists in both
>
>   'Customer.CustomerWeb.Presentation.dll' and
>   'Customer.CustomerContext.dll'` I have to drop a breakpoint before the
>   crash. Inspecting the variable is when I get that message

The namespace collision is not your problem, its causing the debugger to blow up when it is trying to evaluate the variable but I don't see how it could possibly cause a StackOverflow.  You need to either a) look more closely at the linq to figure out where you have some accidental recursion or b) post a portion of the stack trace so that we can help you track it down.